# Centos 6 - cant access the systems IP address until i change it and change back to original (easy question)

Tags: linux, ifconfig

IP system is 192.168.1.100 static
i boot up server i can ping it from the lan (with reply) but can not access services
if i do

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.101 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

then back to

`ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0`

if fixes the problem  i can access all ports again.
What is the cause /solution (i can also access 192.168.1.101 when its set)

iptables is disabled

my ifcfg-eth0:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=no
USERCTL=no
PEERDNS=yes
IPV6INIT=no
```

```
arping -I eth0 -c5 -D 192.168.1.100 && echo OK || echo KO:duplicate
ARPING 192.168.1.100 from 0.0.0.0 eth0
Sent 5 probes (5 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s)
OK
```

thank you

Comment: Is something else on the network using 192.168.1.100?  Check your ARP tables.

Comment: running from this system (the command from the iputils package, not from some arping package) `arping -I eth0 -c5 -D 192.168.1.100 && echo OK || echo KO:duplicate` would help figuring out such problem. (-D stands for "duplicate address detection" so there must be no reply and this will take 5s)

Comment: Hi thank you, the reply was Received 0 response(s)

Comment: i put the output to that command in the question formatted as well

Comment: could it be an ip policy issue?

Comment: found the issue ip- rule broken